# Can't find .sql file in sql query phpmyadmin (#13 Error)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to import a cities .sql file into my table.

I am using this github repository:
https://github.com/JoshSmith/worldwide-city-database

I have created the table, like it says in the repository,
 but when it comes to importing the cities.sql I get an error.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "/tmp/test_data/cities.sql"
        INTO TABLE cities
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
        (combined, population, country_code, region, latitude, longitude);
```

I also have a picture of it:

[image]

I mention that I am using a Mac, have read all the solutions and tried them out, but didn't work. I also made sure my file is in MAMP/tmp/.

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion from the image -> sql query. I have the file in /tmp/test_data/ . I have modified the query to look there.

Comment: Why have you put the file in MAMP/temp, when your SQL query is looking in /tmp/test_data/?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion from the image -> sql query. I have the file in /tmp/test_data/ . I have modified the query to look there.

Answer (score 0):

You have the cities.sql? then you need to create new database ,give name:cities then import into cities your cities.sql file.

Comment: I already have the database. Also the table, called 'cities'. Cities.sql has to be imported into the cities table, like it says in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

You indicated you had the file in MAMP/temp/ ...but the error indicates it's looking for the file in /tmp/test_data/.  Check your tmp vs temp.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion from the image -> sql query. I have the file in /tmp/test_data/ . I have modified the query to look there.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use the phpMyAdmin [UploadDir](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_UploadDir) feature instead. Due to various permissions issues, security means, and other idiosyncrasies those processes can be blocked from reading this file even though you provide the complete path. Using the phpMyAdmin UploadDir, you basically create a folder (mine is a subdirectory of my phpMyAdmin installation), add the directive to `config.inc.php`, and copy the file in there. phpMyAdmin shows it in a dropdown on the Import page. Again, you need proper permissions on the file and folder, but I find it easier than `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

If you prefer to continue to try the MySQL method, my guess is that it's a permissions problem. Make sure the webserver and MySQL processes have the proper permissions on the .sql file (and perhaps also on the directory it's in, though that *probably* shouldn't matter). Your webserver and MySQL error logs might have hints, also.